# Too long select if using JSON fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql

There are two connected models

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex
from django.db import models


class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)
    attributes = models.JSONField(null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'models'
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=['attributes'])]

class Offer(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, db_index=True)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    model = models.ForeignKey('Model', related_name='offers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'offers'
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=['attributes'])]
```

When I make queries using several offer attributes, it takes to many time. What wrong with this code? I have about 5000 models and about 300 000 offers in my db. Query takes about 20 seconds. If I use only one attribute from offer it's ok.

```py
result = (
    Model.objects
    .prefetch_related('offers')
    .filter(attributes__param1='value1')
    .filter(attributes__param2=False)
    .filter(offers__attributes__width='255')
    .filter(offers__attributes__height='55')
    .filter(offers__attributes__diameter='16')
)
```

Comment: big queries will take long time to compute and return the result.

Comment: What SQL gets emitted? What is the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for it?